# If I use iTunes to uninstall an app from my iPhone, should I be able to reinstall it without redownloading it?

Tags: ios

So I thought I could click "Remove" by an app in iTunes, and then later hit "Install" to put it back. But I just get an error that says the app could not be installed because it could not be found.

This is with an iPhone 4 running iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you keep the installer package in your download folder.

Otherwise once removed, you will have to re download.

Comment: I don't recall seeing installer packages in a download folder for iPhone apps. Are you thinking of OSX applications?